# VueJS - Load separate component into vue instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

At my job I'm currently in the progress of a redesign of our web platform, including moving a lot of old **javascript / jquery** into **VueJS**.

I have a `global.js` file which holds our **Vue** components and we have a `vendor.js` which holds **Vue, Axios, Vuex,...**

Now we have a text editor on our site and this editor has a **Vue** version. The problem is that this text editor is pretty big, almost *500kb* minified for production. So I've created a separate component in a separate file for this editor, since we only need it on two pages.

[image]

Now, since my global **Vue** takes up the whole page I cannot insert the text editor into it because you can't put a **Vue** instance inside another **Vue** instance.

Is there a way that I can keep the editor as a totally separate file but somehow use the global **Vue** instance when it gets loaded on a page?

I've searched for quite a bit but haven't come across this problem anywhere. Maybe it's not possible to do this.

Comment: Are you using your own text editor or it is a third party library? Can you just mention what text editor are you using?

Comment: To be clear, the problem you've got is that there's a version mismatch between text editor & the rest of the page? ie "Now we have a text editor on our site and this editor has a Vue version"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try loading `TextEditor.vue` asynchronously.

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  components: {
    TextEditor: () => import("./TextEditor.vue")
  }
})
```

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the CSS for the editor to `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` and put it inside your app component.  Then use a `v-if` to toggle visibility.

You can also wrap your editor using a 3rd party dialog component to wrap it into a modal popup window.

---

Another unrelated suggestion is to use lazy loading if the component has a large size.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge multiple Vue files together through `imports` and the `components` property within a `.vue` file.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <TextEditor></TextEditor>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import TextEditor from 'path/to/TextEditor.vue';

export default {
   name: 'Main',
   components: {
      TextEditor
   }
}
</script>
```

Furthermore, you can set this to be a dynamic import. If your project was set up with `vue-cli`, you should already have webpack installed. If that's the case then you can also set the dynamic import to have one of two types: [prefetch or preload](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules). Essentially prefetch downloads files when the app is idle and preload downloads it in parallel to the main component. Implementing either of those aspects ends up looking like this:

```
export default {
   name: 'Main',
   components: {
      TextEditor: import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ 'path/to/TextEditor.vue')
      /* OR */
      // TextEditor: import(/* webpackPreload: true */ 'path/to/TextEditor.vue')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at splitting your bundle into chunks: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Only load your text editor chunk on pages that require it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a **Vue** instance inside another **Vue** instance.

Let's say I have the following HTML

```
<div id="main-app"></div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#main-app",
  template: `<div>
        This is my main application which has an editor div
        <div id="editor"></div>
     </div>`
});
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#editor",
  template: `<div>
        This is my editor component
     </div>`
});
```

The final resulting HTML would be

```
<div>
  This is my main application which has an editor div
  <div>
    This is my editor component
  </div>
</div>
```